# How can some methods be in the prototype but not be passed around via Object.assign, while some others are

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototype

Take the following classes A, B and C and their instances a, b and c

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.method1 = function() {}
    }

    method2() {}
}

A.prototype.method3 = function() {};


class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}


class C {
    constructor() {}
}

Object.assign(C.prototype, A.prototype);

const a = new A();
const b = new B();
const c = new C();
```

How come class B inherits method 2 but class C doesn't?

How can the following statements be both true ?

```
A.prototype.method2 !== undefined
c.method2 === undefined
```

In case you are wondering, `c.method3 !== undefined`, so there is some fundamental difference between the two that I cannot grasp.

You can fiddle around with it here https://jsfiddle.net/pdn64bv2/

---

**Update**

I thought it would be useful to share how to achieve the effect I was expecting `Object.assign(C.prototype, A.prototype)` to produce.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A.prototype).forEach(name => {
  if (name !== "constructor") C.prototype[name] = A.prototype[name];
});
```

This copies the prototype of A to C, including non-enumerable properties.

Note that it does not copy the hole prototype chain the way `Reflect.setPrototypeOf(C.prototype, A.prototype)` would, which may be interesting for object composition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things conspiring to have this effect:

1) Object.assign will only copy the [enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable) [own properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) of an object. Any non-enumerable properties will not be copied

2) When you use the `class` keyword, any methods you define are *not* enumerable. This is different from when you assign something to an object with `A.prototype.method3 = function() {}`, where the property *will* be enumerable.

So since A.prototype.method2 is not enumerable, it does not get put onto C.prototype when you do `Object.assign(C.prototype, A.prototype);`

Another way to see that class methods aren't enumerable is to use Object.keys. The ones defined with the class keyword are not there:

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.method1 = function() {}
    }

    method2() {}
}

A.prototype.method3 = function() {};

console.log(Object.keys(A.prototype));

console.log(A.prototype.method2); // it's there
console.log(Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable('method2')); // but it's not enumerable
```

Comment: This raises many questions. I need to look that up. Great answer.